# check file exists on url when server is not giving error 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-io, web-hosting

My question is simple.
I want to check if file exist on url or not in PHP.

Something like `file_exist($url)`.

I googled and found lot of solutions, But none of them is working for me.
I think the reason is that My server automatically redirect on error 404.

File is hosted on 000webhost server, And I am checking from my local server.
I checked .htaccess file but didn't found any setting in it.

Please guide me if it is possible to code in php or any setting in 000webhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I found below code from net and worked for me..

```
function is_url_exist($url){
        $ch = curl_init($url);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if($code == 200){
            $status = true;
        }else{
            $status = false;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $status;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Exception Handler using `set_error_handler('exceptionHandler function');`

Here is what is use

```
if (!function_exists('exceptionHandler')) {

    function exceptionHandler($severity, $message, $file, $line)
    {
        if ($severity == E_STRICT) {
            return;
        }
        // code logic to handle or display exceptions
    }
}
```

This would be the way you can have control over handling exceptions and handle 404 exception here

Comment: Hello.. I didn't get from your code... I am searching for file_exist code. Possibly write where to check file on url exist or not?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php which will help capture the code (404). So detect if 404 is called, file_exists or not

Comment: Sir, I read from your link but mainly it describes error handling but there isn't any thing to check file exist or not on url. I have a problem regarding its not giving error 404 if file is not found, so that I am not able to check in function. If I am being able to check that Whether file exist or not then I have no interest in error 404.